# How to speed up the web service in Android?

Tags: android, web-services

Recently I started  learning android.  Now I want know information about web services in android.

1. which web services are fast in android?
2. we need to use any libraries for web service fastness?

My main aim is decrease the web service loading time.

Today I observed that web services are taking more time in below API levels and somewhat better in above API levels.

Please any one suggest me how to decrease web service loading.

Comment: all my  web services are  json based web services. in my splash screen i am calling 5 web services, so splash screen taking so much time.  if it is ok in high level api, but it is taking too much amount of time in below api. please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think a library can be used then you may consider using Square Retrofit. With some benchmarks tested, it is quite snappy when considered with async task. Also you can take a look at volley which is also an option in this case but I would recommend Retrofit for its ease of use. you can consider the following article for some metrics.

[Android Async HTTP Clients: Volley vs Retrofit](http://instructure.github.io/blog/2013/12/09/volley-vs-retrofit/).

Answer (score 0):

JSON based web service is lightweight than XML or any other format so even in the low network connectivity you can expect considerable good performance.

Here is a sample code to connect with JSON based web service

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
    jsonObj.put("username", username);
    jsonObj.put("data", dataValue);

    // Create the POST object and add the parameters
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonObj.toString(), HTTP.UTF_8);
    entity.setContentType("application/json");
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
```

It's always better to make network calls inside AsyncTask so that you can show progress bar while you are dealing with web service